# Restore svn without any backups

Tags: svn, backup, restore

My windows desktop machine died the other day and i had a local svn server running.
Is it possible to restore the repository just from the repo file structure alone?

I know i should have been backing it up, but i didnt for what ever reason, as the code in it was mostly just playing about and experiments.  If the repo cant be restored then its no problem as i have all the working copies locally just like to know if it possible...

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested to use `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` for repository relocation, but a filesystem copy from your restored drive should do the job aswell.

You won't be able to restore any history from your working copies.